# Debugging very slow after adding persistent settings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, performance, visual-studio

I have a semi-small visual C# solution I am working on in Visual Studio 2010. I recently added in Persistent settings using the `settings.Settings` file and `Properties.Settings.Default`. On the Form Load event, I am checking the value using `Properties.Settings.Default` and am assigning them to a `checkbox.Checked` variable.

```
//Load Form1
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    cbxShowPass.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.showFullPassword;
    checkBox2.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.showBookmarkFiles;
}
```

When I start my program in Debug mode, it is extremely slow to start, however, when I remove that line of code, it will start quickly.

What can I do to make my program start up quickly in Debug mode without removing the Settings?

Here are my CheckBox_Changed events, where I assign the value to the Settings.

```
private void ShowPass_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.showFullPassword = !Properties.Settings.Default.showFullPassword;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        DisplayPassword();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code attached to the checkbox change events?  What if you just assign true or false to the check box?  What if you just assign the settings to temporary boolean variables?

Comment: It seems a bit strange that as a result of reading settings, you are saving settings.  It doesn't look recursive but a change to the settings file will cause it to be re-read and re-cached.  That could cause the second reading (setting the second checkbox) to have to wait.

Comment: @SteveWellens Oh, wow, I did not notice that it might cause that to happen! What I meant for this to do was when the user checked the checkbox, it would be saved, and then when they restarted it, it would restore it's checked state. What do you suggest I could do to get rid of that recursive call?

Comment: You could read the settings into the checkboxes and then MANUALLY connect the event handlers in Form Load.